# Blackberry eclipse debugger not reflecting code changes

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, debugging, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I've been struggling with this for the past day. I seem to be stuck with a weird bug in Eclipse where it decides to step through and exec sections that I've entirely deleted or commented. It also chooses to ignore all the instructions that I've actually added today. I've tried removing all breakpoints, clearing my bin directory, resetting my emulator, but nothing works.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks, 
Teja.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the OS you are debugging for...
5.0 + the sim is hot-swappable, and the menu option: Project-BlackBerry-Clean Simulator actually cleans the simulator
Do you have "Build Automatically" checked?  You should (for this anywho)
if you select to Debug while it is running, it will build and resume near to the point it left off (if it still exists after your code edits anyway)

under 5.0, you need to kill the old sim, run the clean.bat as mentioned above and restart the sim

Although upon re-reading your post, sounds more like your build is not making it to the sim, and it is executing the app you already placed on it...  Run the sim's clean.bat and check again...  Are you sure you have a successful build?

Comment: Turns out it wasn't even making it into the simulator because rapc was failing for a different reason. Fixed it now, thanks.

Comment: Hi Tejaswi, I'm facing the same problem, how did you find out that rapc was failing and how did you fix it? I get no error messages on the console but I do see the rapc call.

Comment: Oohh RIM, you suck, big time. It turns out that the rapc command has problems if the path to the project has spaces, so if the username has more than 1 word, it fails. Moved the project to a path with no blank spaces and it worked

Comment: +1 for Curro's answer. Moving the project to a path with no spaces solved this issue for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the solution to your problem but here are a few useful tips:

1.If you make changes to the code and save them while you have started the debugger i.e. have started Eclipse in Debug mode(Debug as...) the debugger won't recognize the changes. You have to recompile, repackage and then restart the debugger.

2.After making the changes to your code it isn't enough to just build the project. You also have to select the project and from the Project menu then Blackberry->Package Projects. After doing this try to start the debugger.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try to clean your emulator if you haven't done this yet. Go to emulator folder and use clean.bat to clean the emulator this will remove all applications you installed on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I make changes to the BB code I need to do a *clean build* in Eclipse, sounds silly but it works for me. Otherwise I get the behavior you describe...